# What are the ways to connect webservices from objective-C/ios other than NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just curious what are other ways to connect webservices from iphone application other than NSURLConnection.

Thanks
Srini

Comment: [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: low level socket connections, tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: If you can add little more information regarding what you're exactly looking, it will be helpful